# Unable to Read from Elasticsearch Using PySpark Connector but Successful with Python Elasticsearch Client

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to read data from Elasticsearch using PySpark's Elasticsearch connector. Surprisingly, I can successfully retrieve data using the Python Elasticsearch client directly. The code snippets and configurations for both approaches are provided below:

Python Elasticsearch Client (successful):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(
    f"https://{CONN_ENV}:{PORT}",
    basic_auth=(USER, PASSWORD),
    verify_certs=False,
    request_timeout=150
)

response = es.search(index=INDEX_NAME_START, size=10000)
print(response["hits"]["hits"][1])
```

PySpark Elasticsearch Connector (encountering issues):

```
es_options = {
    "es.nodes": CONN_ENV,
    "es.port": PORT,
    "es.resource": INDEX_NAME_START,
    "es.net.http.auth.user": USER,
    "es.net.http.auth.pass": PASSWORD,
    "es.net.ssl": False,
    "es.nodes.wan.only": "true",
}

es_dataframe = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .options(**es_options) \
    .load()
```

Error Encountered:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings) - all nodes failed; tried
```

Note: I'm using the Elasticsearch connector version org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:8.9.1, which matches the Elasticsearch version.

I'd like to understand why there's a discrepancy between successfully accessing Elasticsearch using the Python Elasticsearch client and encountering connection issues with PySpark's Elasticsearch connector, despite using the same Elasticsearch version. Any insights or troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I saw you set `es.net.ssl` options as Python value `False` instead of a string value like `es.nodes.wan.only`. Have you tried setting it as "false" or "true" instead?

Comment: Also I think you connected to elastic search with "https" on elasticsearch client so shouldn't the `es.net.ssl` value be "true" for pyspark conenctor?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried but I get the same error. "es_options = {
    "es.nodes": CONN_ENV,
    "es.port": PORT,
    "es.resource": INDEX_NAME_START,
    "es.net.http.auth.user": USER,
    "es.net.http.auth.pass": PASSWORD,
    "es.net.ssl": "true",
    "es.nodes.wan.only": "true",
}

es_dataframe = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .options(**es_options) \
    .load()"